# Empty network related files appearing in home directory periodically

Tags: networking, 22.04, aws

Why are these empty files appearing in my home directory periodically?

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Jun 22 05:40 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-9e994000.13551491757067348536736786
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Jun 22 05:45 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-dcb91000.13552798431720516204453119
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Jun 22 05:50 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-5b79f000.1355423-7902286281734704055
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Jul 20 18:05 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-efa1000.2593015-9040217368033700320
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Jul 20 18:10 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-c9999000.2593164-654493751343397647
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Aug  4 18:00 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-19dad000.3153703-3087855922850392740
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Aug  4 18:10 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-c6191000.31539315807178165870851184
-rw-rw-rw-  1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Aug  4 18:20 ip-172-31-15-<censored>-cc79d000.3154173-3441805638165526180
```

The files are all empty with a name in the following format:

**local network address name**-**4 byte hex string**.**19 digit number, sometimes with a '-' character after the 7th digit, sometimes without**

This is Ubuntu 22.04 running in AWS, and I've confirmed that the IP address at the start corresponds to my local IP address on the primary network interface. Is this a DHCP job? I seem to get more of these logs in bursts, but the times the files are created seem to be at even intervals, most of the time. I'm not sure how well it's correlated with when I'm logged into the server doing stuff.

Perhaps there is a standard Ubuntu process or AWS specific job on the Ubuntu images that might cause this log?

Comment: This is not happening on my Ubuntu Server, so I'm guessing it's AWS specific.